# Session variable passing

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I've got a php script which builds a html table via echoing data, But i want to add a link onto one of the values and pass that value to the next page.

```
<td><a href='redirect.php'><?php $_SESSION['WR'] = $row['WorkOrdRef'];echo $row['WorkOrdRef'];?></a></td>
```

is the line in question but this will only pass the last value added to the table.

Comment: Why you want to pass value from sessiion in link if you can still access it through session anyway?

Comment: @maque the link will bring up the next page where the variable will be used

Comment: then why not just go to the next page and then access them from session!

Comment: @KhairulIslam the session variable only stores the last value put into the table, for example this column would contain '1','2','3' in each row then when you click on the link for one the variable passed over will be 3 not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it doesnt work like this. the php code gets executed no matter if you click the link.

I guess the easiest way to do this is to pass it as a get parameter.

**html page:**

```
<a href="redirect.php?clickedcell=WorkOrdRef"><?=$cellContent?></a>
```

**redirect.php:**

```
$clickedcell = $_GET['clickedcell']
```

now the $clickedcell will have the data from the previous page about what cell did the user click.

If you want to use session for some reason, you still have to pass it with GET or POST and store it after the user clicks.

hopefully this is understandable and good luck with your project.

Comment: Perfect just what i needed and makes sense

Comment: Hey Danny. Happy to help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can change the session by get method also it is possible building by javascript

in the same page add this

```
if(isset($_GET["clicked"])){
 $_SESSION['WR'] = $row['WorkOrdRef'];
$redirect'<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL='.$adres.'/"> ';
return $redirect;
}
```

and then change your url

```
<td><a href="?clicked=ok"><?php echo $row['WorkOrdRef'];?></a></td>
```